# How can I use same URL and IP when I migrate from VM to physical server in tableau?

Tags: dns, tableau-api

We are currently having a Tableau production server (tableau.xyz.com) and we are installing another new server. We are not upgrading because, we are changing from VM to Physical host. Now, we need the same URL and same IP. We are not interested in doing IP swap from old prod server machine to new prod server machine. Can any tableau expertise suggest how to do?

Comment: "Now, we need the [..] same IP. We are not interested in doing IP swap from old prod server machine to new prod server machine."  I'm not clear exactly what you want.  You want to move the IP or don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your physical hostname as a virtual host.
you should use a domain name instead of IP address.